# Dotted x in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, accents, code

I want a dot over my variable x inside Gödel-codes, and used the following code `$\exists x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x)}}$`,  with this in the preamble to have nice corner quotes:

```
\newbox\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnCornerHgt
\setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$\ulcorner$}
\global\gnCornerHgt=\ht\gnBoxA
\newdimen\gnArgHgt
\def\Godelnum #1{%
    \setbox\gnBoxA=\hbox{$#1$}%
    \gnArgHgt=\ht\gnBoxA%
    \ifnum     \gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt \gnArgHgt=0pt%
    \else \advance \gnArgHgt by -\gnCornerHgt%
    \fi \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\ulcorner$} \box\gnBoxA %
    \raise\gnArgHgt\hbox{$\urcorner$}}
```

But the dot is too high up to the right. How can I obtain a normal dot above the variable x?

Comment: Did you try a simple `\dot{x}`?

Comment: As Bernard writes, type `A(\dot{x})` instead of `A(\dot{x)}`.

Comment: @Bernard I need the Gödel codes

Comment: @Sapiens. When I type `$\exists x \mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x})}$` the dotted x looks exactly the same as with `$\exists x \mathcal{T} A(\dot{x})$`. Either the problem is the one hair-splitter points out, that you're including the `')` inside the `\dot{..}` or there is some other setting affecting your document we don't know about.

Comment: @frabjous I used \ulcorner\urcorner, but am not quite satisifed with how they appear.

Comment: @Sapiens I don't understand how that's relevant. You can use the code you posted above. The problem with the dot over the x is completely unrelated to the code for the Gödel numbering, and is just the result of a silly typo, but for some reason you aren't reading the comments properly. See hair-splitter's comment and read it carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented, you have

```
\Godelnum{A(\dot{x)}}
```

so the dot is placed above the combination `x)`, hence it is higher and centered with respect to both items.

You should fix into

```
\Godelnum{A(\dot{x})}
```

[image]

The top one is your input, the bottom one is the fixed one.

However, your code is not really LaTeX savvy and you can dispense with setting boxes, by using proper LaTeX code (your code also has a couple of mistakes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newlength{\gnCornerHgt}
\newlength{\gnArgHgt}

\newcommand{\Godelnum}[1]{%
  \settoheight{\gnCornerHgt}{$\ulcorner$}%
  \settoheight{\gnArgHgt}{$#1$}%
  \ifdim\gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt
    \setlength{\gnArgHgt}{0pt}%
  \else
    \addtolength{\gnArgHgt}{-\gnCornerHgt}%
  \fi
  \raisebox{\gnArgHgt}{$\ulcorner$}%
  #1%
  \raisebox\gnArgHgt{$\urcorner$}%
}

\begin{document}

$x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x)}}$

$x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x})}$

$x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}}$

\end{document}
```

The length `\gnCornerHgt` should be set at run time, because it must depend on the current font size.

The `\ifnum` is really wrong as well as the `%` after `0pt`. In this case TeX has a protection mechanism, but you end up with an unwanted token (precisely a “frozen” `\relax`).

[image]

I know that `\Godelnum` of a matrix doesn't really make sense, I used it to show that the height is the desired one.

A version that also change sizes in subscripts or superscripts. I add a `\LARGE` version to show that it works in different font sizes as well.

Note the addition of `\mathinner` that adds a thin space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newlength{\gnCornerHgt}
\newlength{\gnArgHgt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Godelnum}[1]{\mathinner{\mathpalette\Godelnum@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Godelnum@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settoheight{\gnCornerHgt}{$\m@th#1\ulcorner$}%
  \settoheight{\gnArgHgt}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
  \ifdim\gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt
    \setlength{\gnArgHgt}{0pt}%
  \else
    \addtolength{\gnArgHgt}{-\gnCornerHgt}%
  \fi 
  \raisebox{\gnArgHgt}{$\m@th#1\ulcorner$}%
  #2%
  \raisebox\gnArgHgt{$\m@th#1\urcorner$}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x})}$

$x_{\Godelnum{y}}$

\LARGE
$x\mathcal{T}\Godelnum{A(\dot{x})}$

\end{document}
```

[image]