# Gödel codes with rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, tikz-styles

The simplest way to produce Gödel codes is with `$\ulcorner$` and `$\urcorner$`, and we may write `$\ulcorner p\urcorner$` to enclose the formula `$p$` within codes.

Buss programmed a macro which gives a better appearance than Gödel codes  in many contextst.

The macro Godeln{}, which egreg  recently suggested, as an aside in an answer to a recent question ([Dotted x in mathmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648140/dotted-x-in-mathmode)), is an improvement of Buss's improvements of `\(\ulcorner \urcorner\)`.

My question is: *May the corners of the egreg codes be rounded, e.g. with TikZ, to obtain codes which are discernibly different?*

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newlength{\gnCornerHgt}
\newlength{\gnArgHgt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Godeln}[1]{\mathinner{\mathpalette\Godeln@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Godeln@}[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \settoheight{\gnCornerHgt}{$\m@th#1\ulcorner$}%
    \settoheight{\gnArgHgt}{$\m@th#1#2$}%
    \ifdim\gnArgHgt<\gnCornerHgt
    \setlength{\gnArgHgt}{0pt}%
    \else
    \addtolength{\gnArgHgt}{-\gnCornerHgt}%
    \fi 
    \raisebox{\gnArgHgt}{$\m@th#1\ulcorner$}%
    #2%
    \raisebox\gnArgHgt{$\m@th#1\urcorner$}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    $\ulcorner 2^2\urcorner$ vs. $\Godeln{2^2}$
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I fear, I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but you cannot simply round the corner of a glyph, in this case the glyphs which the macros `\ulcorner` and `\urcorner` output. You cannot transform the path of a glyph, but you can use another glyph or you can create your own "rounded corner" glyphs using Ti*k*Z if this is what you want.

Comment: Having said that, it would be nice if you could clean up your question and make it better readable for others. It is not a good idea in my opinion that your put the question inside your MWE. Question and MWE should be separate parts of the post.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks, I did some more edits, which I think also clarify that the question is on whether "you can create your own "rounded corner" glyphs using Tikz.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. I did this for you but you undid my edit.

Comment: @SandyG I did it inadvertently, I believe.

Comment: No problem. I reformatted it. Hope that's ok.

Comment: @SandyG Good. Now my problem is that it does not compile in the presence of all my other packages, as amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, mathtools and others. Are there known conflicts between TikZ and other packages?

Comment: @SandyG It compiled! :) I used upper case G and not lower case g as you.  

Thanks again!

Comment: @SandyG Interestingly, it does not, as its counterparts, compile in section headings.

Comment: You need to `\protect` it in a section heading. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A variant of Sandy G's code. The main differences are

1. how the baseline is treated, so we're guaranteed that the symbol has the correct one
2. the argument to `\godel` is typeset in math mode.
3. the sidebearings are fixed and don't shrink nor stretch

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\sandygodel}[2][]{{}\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz{
  \node[inner ysep=-1pt, inner xsep=3pt](M){#2\strut};
  \draw[rounded corners=.5mm, #1]([xshift=-.3em]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.3em);
  \draw[rounded corners=.5mm, #1]([xshift=.3em]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.3em);
}}}}{}}


\newcommand{\godel}[2][]{%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(M.south)]
    \node[inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=3pt](M){\smash[b]{$#2\mathstrut$}};
    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm,#1]([xshift=-1mm]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.1);
    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm,#1]([xshift=1mm]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Egreg's $\godel{A}$ and $\godel[thick]{A}$}

Some examples: $\godel{a}\godel{A}\godel{g}\godel{(}$

Squeezed: \hbox spread -10pt{$\godel{a}\godel{A}$}

Math: $\godel{r\in R}$

\medskip

{\Large Some examples: $\godel{a}\godel{A}\godel{g}\godel{(}$}

\section{Sandy's $\sandygodel{A}$ and $\sandygodel[thick]{A}$}

Some examples: $\sandygodel{a}\sandygodel{A}\sandygodel{g}\sandygodel{(}$

Squeezed: \hbox spread -10pt{$\sandygodel{a}\sandygodel{A}$}

Math: $\sandygodel{$r\in R$}$

\medskip

{\Large Some examples: $\sandygodel{a}\sandygodel{A}\sandygodel{g}\sandygodel{(}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Does this produce another out pute than your answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674695/how-may-i-protect-this-godel-command-for-section-titles/674702#674702 ?

Comment: @Sapiens The version here is more refined.

Comment: Great! I accept your answer, as a guidance for those who might be interested in finding the best available answer to  my query. But Sandy G deserves much recognition as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a somewhat simpler draw-it-yourself version with Ti*k*Z. You can adjust the radius of the rounded corners by changing the `.5mm` in the `\draw` commands. You can adjust the horizontal spacing by changing `inner xsep`, and the vertical spacing by changing `inner ysep`.

[image]

There is also an optional argument that can be used to change the `\draw` style. For example, `\godel[thick]{a}`. Colors work too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\godel}[2][]{{}\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz{
  \node[inner ysep=-1pt, inner xsep=3pt](M){#2\strut};
  \draw[rounded corners=.5mm, #1]([xshift=-.3em]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.3em);
  \draw[rounded corners=.5mm, #1]([xshift=.3em]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.3em);
}}}}{}}

\begin{document}

Some examples: $\godel{a}\godel{A}\godel{g}\godel{(}$

\section{Here is a G\"odel code $\godel[thick]{a}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. With me \section{ $\protect\godel[thick]{A}$} gives many errors so that the document does not compile.
The first error is:
Argument of \pgfkeys@temp has an extra }. \section{ $\protect\godel[thick]{A}$}

Comment: @Sapiens: I can't reproduce that error. Maybe a typo? If you can't figure it out you could post a new question with a link to this one.

Comment: What gave me problems was: \section{$\protect\godel[thick]{A}$ is ...}.

Comment: No, I almost resolved it by using: : \section{~} {\Large \noindent \textbf{19} \indent $\godel{A}$ \textbf{is true just if the end of A is truth}} A drawback is that there is now a lineshift after the Section number.

Comment: I posted the following question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674634/may-we-avoid-the-line-break-after-section-title.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce any of the errors @Sapiens says he (or she?) is getting.

Comment: As @egreg suggested, I changed the code to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: Since you have added an optional argument, using `\DeclareRobustCommand` is not necessary.

Comment: @SandyG Many thanks for your efforts! I now accepted Greg's answer, as a guidance for those who might be interested in finding the best available answer to the query. But you deserve much recognition as well!