# How may I protect this \godel command for section titles?

Tags: section-titles

In the first version of the answer to my question [Gödel codes with rounded Cornes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/674275/g%C3%B6del-codes-with-rounded-corners/674522?noredirect=1#comment1676009_674522), Sandy G offered the following solution:

```
\newcommand{\godel}[1]{{}\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz{
                    \node[inner ysep=-1pt, inner xsep=3pt](M){$#1\strut$};
                    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=-1mm]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.1);
                    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=1mm]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.1);
    }}}}{}}
```

The solution is quite satisfactory for my document, except that many errors are produced, so that the document does not compile, if I put $\godel{A}$ in the title of a section. I tried two ways to protect it, via. $\protect\godel{A}\protect$ and $\protect\godel[thick]{A}$.

Are there other ways to protect $\godel{A}$ in section titles which may help me out?

Comment: `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`

Comment: Please edit your query to reproduce some of the error messages you say you're getting. The reason I ask for this is that executing  either `\subsection{.$\godel{a}$.}` or `\subsection{.$\godel[thick]{a}$.}`(with the macro `\godel` having been copied from the answer you reference) produces no errors on my system -- MacOS 13.2 "Ventura"; MacTeX2022; pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24; LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1; and L3 programming layer <2023-02-07>. Note that I don't find there's a need for `\protect`.

Comment: Incidentally, what makes you think that "Sandy G" is a male?

Comment: @egreg Unfortunately that did not succeed.

Comment: @Sapiens - Please tell us more about your TeX distribution and when you last updated it.

Comment: @Mico I don't know whether the difference between our programs might make a difference. I use MacOS 11.7.1 Big Sur,  and Tex Studio 4.3.1. Another possibility I thought about was whether package conflicts could cause the problem, but it persists even with only

Comment: @MicoI In the meantime I did.

Comment: TeXstudio is a front end or editor, not a TeX distribution. Do you employ MacTeX? (MacTeX *is* a TeX distribution.) If so, which vintage, and when did you last update it?

Comment: I think there may be a package conflict. I am able to avoid the problem with a small subset of the packages I use, and will see if I may reach an understanding of what happens, and resolve the problem.

Comment: @Mico How may I see this? Finder was just modified, by the way...

Comment: @Sapiens - Check the first line of the log file (in `\jobname.log`). In my log file, the first line -- which is quite long -- says `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.2.9)  9 FEB 2023 23:10`. MacTeX is TeX Live with some graphical tools. The log file is produced by TeX, *not* by Finder.

Comment: @Mico This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.11.4)  9 FEB 2023 18:57
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.

Comment: So I'm using Tex Live 2022

Comment: The problem is not caused by a conflict with other packages in the preamble.

Comment: The problem is not caused by the preamble, or by using \tableofcontens.

Comment: I may have found the problem. \godel{} does not accept mathematical expressions like \exists u(u\in u) as argument. It does, however, accept $\exists u(u\in u)$.

Answer (score 1):

This works flawlessly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\godel}{}% just to avoid redefining
\DeclareRobustCommand{\godel}[1]{%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[inner ysep=-1pt, inner xsep=3pt](M){$#1\strut$};
      \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=-1mm]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.1);
      \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=1mm]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }}%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$x\godel{A}y$}

\end{document}
```

Note that I've changed how to space the construction: using `{}\mathbin{...}{}` introduces *flexible* space, that's obviously not wanted: if the formula turns out to need shrinking the space might disappear. Not with `\mspace{1\medmuskip}`, which is not flexible (and the same amount added by default around a `\mathbin`).

[image]

A better definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\godel}[1]{%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
  \vphantom{#1}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(M.south)]
    \node[inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=3pt](M){\smash[b]{$#1\mathstrut$}};
    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=-1mm]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.1);
    \draw[rounded corners=.5mm]([xshift=1mm]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{$x\godel{A}y$}

a $\godel{f}$ b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Unfortunately it does not compile my 50 page document, whereas the solution provided by Sandy G now works, after five hours of editing. The main error I had done was to write, e.g. $\godel{r\in r}$, and not $\godel{$r\in r$}$. I will be interested in using your approach in new documents, from the beginning.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674742/4427 for a more refined version of the code