# How can I produce this expression in latex: ⌜A⌝?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I want
to introduce a unique operator in my document. I basically want it to look like this: `⌜A⌝`, where `A` is just an arbitrary statement. So '⌜⌝' is the operator.

How can I produce the `⌜` and `⌝` symbols here? The closest I've gotten so far are the `\lceil` and `\rceil` commands, but they're not really satisfying since they're way too large. It just looks like this: `⌈A⌉`.
How could I create a new command for the type of operator I'm looking for?

I'm using `amsmath` and LuaLaTeX on overleaf in case that's relevant here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 12):

If the versions of the `\ulcorner` and `\urcorner` symbols provided by the `amssymb` package are a bit too large for your taste, you could try those provided by the `unicode-math` package.

[image]

Depending on the letter that forms the argument of `\upcorner`, some fine-tuning may be needed. E.g., for the letter `T`, the output of `\upcorner{\,T}` looks better than that of `\upcorner{T}`.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}    % for \DeclarePairedDelimiter macro
\usepackage{unicode-math} % for \ulcorner and \urcorner macros
\newcommand\upcorner[1]{\ulcorner\!#1\urcorner}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil\lceil\rceil % just for comparison

\begin{document}
$\upcorner{A}\ \upcorner{B}\ \upcorner{C}\ \dots\ 
 \upcorner{X}\ \upcorner{Y}\ \upcorner{Z}$

$\scriptstyle\upcorner{A}\ \upcorner{B}\ \upcorner{C}\ \dots\ 
 \upcorner{X}\ \upcorner{Y}\ \upcorner{Z}$
 
$\scriptscriptstyle\upcorner{A}\ \upcorner{B}\ \upcorner{C}\ \dots\ 
 \upcorner{X}\ \upcorner{Y}\ \upcorner{Z}$


\medskip
$\upcorner{A}$ vs.\ $\ceil{A}$  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could try `\urcorner` and `\ulcorner` from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
 \ulcorner T \urcorner
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can search on `"C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\doc\latex\comprehensive\symbols-a4.pdf"` by `\ulcorner`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{MnSymbol}
% \usepackage{fdsymbol}
% \usepackage{stix}
% \usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\ulcorner A\urcorner$ amssymb
% $\ulcorner A\urcorner$ MnSymbol
% $\ulcorner A\urcorner$ fdsymbol
% $\ulcorner A\urcorner$ stix
% $\ulcorner A\urcorner$ mathabx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/248821)

Comment: okay, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A variant of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/674742/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\godel}{m}{{\mathpalette\godel@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\godel@}[2]{%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
  \vphantom{#2}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(M.south)]
    \node[inner ysep=0pt,inner xsep=3pt](M){\smash[b]{$\m@th#1\mathstrut#2$}};
    \draw([xshift=-1mm]M.north east)--(M.north east)--++(0,-.1);
    \draw([xshift=1mm]M.north west)--(M.north west)--++(0,-.1);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \mspace{1\medmuskip}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\godel{A}$

$\godel{a+b}$

\medskip

$\displaystyle\godel{\sum_{n\ge0}a_n}$

\end{document}
```

[image]